# Word for problem listening/speaking and not reading/writing english

Tags: word-choice, listening

Suppose I have problems

- listening and understanding English esp. of non-Indian accent
- speaking English fluently

How should I tell someone about it using very few words instead of typing a long sentence?

Comment: Verbal as opposed to written?

Comment: Say you have limited ***oral*** fluency, and if they object that this only covers *speech* (not *listening*), point out that what you actually said was ***aural***.

Comment: "I have difficulty with spoken English."

Answer (score 1):

Consider "nonconversational English."

> [I'm not a certified teacher, but an American student, and could help with conversational and nonconversational English](http://expat.ru/forum/showthread.php?t=290702).

To tell someone you're nonconversational in English, you could say:

> I'm not conversational in English, but I can read it and write it without any difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell them that you are not proficient when it comes to verbal communication. Or your verbal communication skills are to be improved.

Comment: does verbal covers listening too?

Comment: The word *verbose* is defined as "spoken rather than written; oral" thus I would not say it "covers listening" but I believe listening plays a huge role in verbal communication.

Comment: @0arch: that is certainly not what _verbose_ means to me (which is roughly "using too many words"). Did you mean _verbal_?

Comment: @ColinFine Yup. Thanks for pointing it out. It was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

[ESL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_as_a_foreign_or_second_language) -The acronym is well-used for difficulty in either listening or speech